# Allocated memory is increasing rapidly with Firebase and Facebook authentication

Tags: android, memory-leaks, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-memory

I am trying to archive an simple authentication with Facebook and Firebase. But somehow my allocated memory is increasing like crazy. I have no clue what is causing it.. Would any help me out?

It is hard to see, but the allocated size is increasing at about 0.2 MB/s

[image: memory monitor]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Intent navigationIntent;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    // FIREBASE
    private FirebaseAPI firebaseAPI;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

    // FACEBOOK
    private CallbackManager FBcallbackManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        navigationIntent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);

        // Initialize Firebase
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if (user != null) {
                    user.getToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                            sharedPreferences.edit()
                                    .putString("token", task.getResult().getToken())
                                    .apply();

                            Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
                            firebaseAPI = new FirebaseAPI();
                            firebaseAPI.writeUserProfile(Profile.getCurrentProfile());

                            startHomeActivity();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };

        // Initialize Facebook Login button
        FBcallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");
        loginButton.registerCallback(FBcallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        FBcallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (firebaseAuthListener != null) {
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
        }

    }

    private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken accessToken) {

        final AuthCredential authCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken.getToken());

        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            }
        });

    }


    private void startHomeActivity() {
        if (navigationIntent != null) {

            startActivity(navigationIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

**Application**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        App.context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:24.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fully deleting my project and rebuilding it from Version Control, the memory bug disappeared.. (:

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Try removing Crash Reporting from your build.  The [documentation describes a known issue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known-issues) that affects apps that subclass `Application`.  It's not clear what the initialization you perform in your `App.onCreate()` method does, but as the known issues description explains, that processing will be performed twice: once for your app process, and once for the Crash Reporting process.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, sadly this is not working :(. But thanks for pointing out the bug (: